MyBatis Mapping Xml Issue
I was writing this project and I have this problem about the mapping. I am doing something wrong but I cannot find it. I've also checked the document of MyBatis but I couldn't find any update info.
I'm trying to map the List to List. However, I come across with the typeOf and property errors. Is it about the syntax? It is almost 5:30 am in Istanbul and I am losing sleep :/
Besides, Shouldn't I have a mapper(repository) package for this transformation or am I going in the right direction?-->Repository<-- -->XML<--
I am trying to do the relevant transformation and be able to manage contact message crud operations :)

I'm not sure where to start... I would suggest you to start from a simple working project and make small changes one by one. This way, you would know the cause when something went wrong. Here are some project templates. And, please use text for posting code, not images.
